# C# Read attributes from Generic class without instance

Tags: c#, generics, static, attributes

## Problem Description

I'm trying to implement a very specific sort of cache of objects that I may not be able to instantiate directly (private constructors for instance)

What I want to do is read some information about the particular class, preferably through some kind of interface (which sadly doesn't support static methods defined for every subclass)

In other words:

```
public class Data
{
     public static bool Attribute1() => False;
     private Data(...) { ... }
}

public class Cache<T> // T is for instance Data
{
     void SomeMethod() 
     {
          bool Value = T.Attribute1()
          ...
     }
}
```

It's fine if I can make T inherit from some base class or some interface, and to get the attribute through some sort of method or directly. It is very important though that I can

- Program multiple data classes A and B, where A.Attribute1() is different from B.Attribute1()
- Get the attribute from the data class type without instantiating the data type

## Current Solution

I do currently have a solution in the shape of a registry built when the static objects are initialised, like this:

```
class CacheAttributesRegistry
{
    static RegisterAttributes(Type T, bool Attribute1, ...) { ... }
}  

class Data 
{
    static Data() { RegisterAttributes(typeof(Data), true, ...); }
}

class Cache<T>
{
    void SomeMethod()
    {
        bool Value = CacheAttributesRegistry.Attribute1(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

It does exactly what I want, but I'd prefer avoiding a static constructor in every data class, also I don't want it to be possible to accidentally call `RegisterAttributes` at runtime.

Preferably I'd also avoid reflection because I'd like it to be obvious how to set the attributes for a class without the code magically inferring it in the background.

Am I missing some option or have I just reached some language limitations?

Comment: This is sounding like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378): you're asking for help with the solution you decided on, without telling us what problem you are trying to solve. Why do you need different types with a static `bool`?

Comment: Mind you, I did something very similar recently (except with an `int` for each type), but my reasons may be different than yours, so my solution may not be best for you.

Comment: If the static Attribute1() is a constant for every class, you could consider transforming into - umm - an attribute, I mean `[Attribute1(false)] public class Data`